# How can reserve space for an image I don't yet have in a default-style UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, uitableview, uiimageview

I'm trying to use a UITableViewCell with UITableViewCellStyleDefault to display a cell that will eventually have an image in its imageView (after loading it from the interwebs.)

However, when I try to set the the cell's `imageView.frame` to the correct size, the cell just doesn't use reserve the space for the image view (the text is left-aligned rather than having a blank space where the image will go.)

Is there a way to programmatically have the image view be a certain size without having an image in it?

I'd rather avoid subclassing UITableViewCell or including a blank image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like if you want to use the imageView frame itself to reserve the space you are going to need a blank image. In the past I have used a loading image as a placeholder. Maybe you can try adjusting the detailTextLabel either by padding with space until the image loads or adjusting its position. I would recommend a blank/loading image.

> **imageView** Returns the image view of
>   the table cell. (read-only)
>
> @property(nonatomic, readonly, retain)
>   UIImageView *imageView
>
> **Discussion**
>
> Returns the image view (UIImageView
>   object) of the table view, which
>   initially has no image set. ***If an
>   image is set***, it appears on the left
>   side of the cell, before any label.
>   UITableViewCell creates the image-view
>   object when you create the cell.

Comment: That's what I figured. It looks like the imageView gets sizeToFit called on it so any frame change doesn't take effect. It turns out there's other behavior I'm looking to customize so I'm just going to make a subclass of UITableViewCell.